# MonkeyTalk (2.0.4) Android (KitKat) - ActionBar overflow menu support?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat, monkeytalk

Does MonkeyTalk support the overflow menu in Android(KitKat)? I'm testing on version 2.0.4 and pressing on the overflow menu list items isn't being recorded.
Has anyone else run into this problem, found a work around or fix?

Comment: I have also ran into this problem when trying to access an item from a ActionbarSherlock dropdown menu. Issues as well with selection in DialogFragments, ContextMenus and Device menus (ex. choosing an image selection option: gallery/take photo/dropbox/etc.) Come on MonkeyTalk... get it together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the MonkeyTalk devs never answered me directly on their forum, their newest release "August 25, 2014 - MonkeyTalk Community v2.0.8" among other things contains "ActionBar overflow items now supported". So looks like they finally addressed this problem.